# split de um numero inteiro em c++

Tags: c++

Fiz o seguinte programa abaixo que advinha a idade da pessoa e o numero que ela pensou, porem o resultado final gera um numero de 4 algarismos de acordo com os cálculos abaixo suponhamos que eu tenha pensado no numero 12:

Multiplique por 2:
12*2=24

adicione 5:
24+5=29

Multiplique por 50:
29*50=1450

```
std::cout<<"Digite o rsultado: 1450";
std::cin>>result=1450;

int var1(2017-250);
int var2(1450+1767);

std::cout<<"\n\tDigite seu ano de nascimento: ";
std::cin>>anonasc;

int var3(3217-1994);
```

O resultado contido em var3 seria 1223 onde 12 seria o numero que eu tivesse pensado e 23 a minha idade, porem tem alguma forma de separar este resultado para que ele mostre separadamente o numero pensado e a idade da pessoa?

eu sei que se eu fizer:

```
var3=1223/100;
```

ele me retorna

```
var3=12
```

mas e pra eu pegar o numero 23 como eu faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mais correto seria mesmo fazer `var3 % 100` para apanhar o `23`

Não nos podemos esquecer que o `%` (modulo) dá o resto da divisão e por isso apanha o que não se conseguiu dividir.

Exemplo:

```
1223 / 100 = 12
```

Se fizermos `12 * 100` temos `1200`, então o que sobrou e não conseguiu dividir foi `1223 - 1200 = 23`

Vejamos o mesmo principio de divisão e resto analisando um caso simples de `5` a dividir por `2`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui vemos que:

- `5 / 2 = 2`
- `5 % 2 = 1` que é o valor que sobrou.

Note que se considerou a divisão inteira.

[Exemplo online de obter ambas as partes do número](https://ideone.com/GYunf0)

**Conclusão**

Sempre que quiser dividir um número em duas partes, tem apanhar a divisão e o resto da divisão pelo múltiplo de `10` que interessa (10, 100, 1000, etc...)

Comment: Legal fiz o programa usei a primeira dica da resposta acima e funcionou agora reeditei e foi blzera https://pastebin.com/d6bmeCez

Answer (score 1):

Não programo em `C++` mas para você recuperar `23` faça o seguinte:

```
int number = 1223;
int digit = number % 50;
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/M9qlYt)

> Não sei se essa é a melhor solução, talvez alguém com experiência possa responder melhor a pergunta.

Comment: deu certo aqui mas queria entender por que  number%50?

Comment: `number % 50` é o mesmo que `1223 % 50`

Comment: eu sei isso eu entendi mas por que 50 e nao qualquer outro numero?

Comment: Essa é uma dúvida que não posso responder, mas você pode abrir uma pergunta, e alguém com experiência em `C++` te responder com corretamente.